# Orientation of ortho camera on scene

Tags: angular, typescript

In the center of the scene is the object in the upper right corner is the orientation cube[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xW1R.jpg). The camera rotates around the scene freely. At the same time I need to rotate the cube and show the user from which side the camera is looking at the scene.

The essence of the problem: I calculate the angle of the camera from:

```
var pLocal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
var pWorld = pLocal.applyMatrix4(this.camera.matrixWorld);
var dir = pWorld.sub(this.camera.position).normalize();
console.log(this.graduse(dir.x), this.graduse(dir.y), this.graduse(dir.z));

I made a small table depending on the angle[2].

In practice, it turns out that while the camera moves around the cube, the angles of Y and Z change. It is impossible to make the angle of rotation of the orientation cube along the Y axis calculated accurately and smoothly. This is especially noticeable when moving from the front side to the back side.
```

I tried to set the proportional change law with coefficients:

```
[private tableCubeViewRotateCalc: number\[\]\[\] = \[\[-1.58, 90.6\], \[1.58, 0.6\], \[1.58, 0.6\]\];

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.camera.getWorldDirection(vector);

    result_angle.y = this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[2\]\[0\] * (this.graduse(vector.x)) + this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[2\]\[1\];
    if (this.graduse(vector.z) < 0) {//for view back
      if (result_angle.y > 0) {
        result_angle.y += this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[0\]\[0\] * (this.graduse(vector.z)) + this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[0\]\[1\];
      } else {
        result_angle.y -= this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[0\]\[0\] * (this.graduse(vector.z)) + this.tableCubeViewRotateCalc\[0\]\[1\];
      }
    }]

however, this method does not provide the desired accuracy.
```

I read a lot of articles about vector geometry in games, however, I did not find a solution to the problem there.

need some kind of trigonometric relation between Y and Z that would accurately calculate the camera angle

Comment: I found a way to determine the camera angle in spherical coordinates. Arctan (x / z) is required. I t is work.